# Clients' Recommender in Python/R using Graph Theory

Tags: r, python, recommender-system, graph-theory

I have an idea to create a clients' recommender based on their preferences.

Previously there was an experience for me to do those tasks using collaborative filtering technics and associative rules. Now I want to make more progress and dive in graph theory methods to make this task (as far as I know, some companies like Facebook and Booking.com use graph concepts to understand clients preference).

Maths aspects're more familiar to me than programming ones in terms of this task so I'm searching some useful example of how to do that in Python/R.

So can you please recommend some useful links or materials for Python (or R) realization of the concept from which I can start on doing because I'm quite new in this area.

Thanks!